# Adding a reference to an existing record in has_many through: association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to have a form that will add an existing record to a has_many through: by searching on a field using Ruby on Rails 4.

My models are as follows:

```
class Offering < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: :enrolments
  has_many :enrolments
end

class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offering
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offerings, through: :enrolments
  has_many :enrolments
end
```

On my Offering's **show** page I'd like to have a "Add Student by Student ID" form. The user would type in the student's student id (i.e. *not* the ID of the rails record), and submit to add the association.

(Optimally the page would, on entry of a valid student ID and before submit, automatically show the full name of the student about to be added)

But I'm fairly newbie, and I'm not sure how to go about setting this up. My expectation would be something like this:

```
<h4>Add Student</h4>
<%= form_for @offering do |f| %>
  <p>
    Student ID: <%= f.text_field @sid %><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add Student" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Where sid is a local variable I can use to lookup the student in the controller and add using `@offering.students << Student.search()`.

But I'm just not sure, and would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge and solved it using the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem and a little Jquery.

The has_many :through associations in my models had the same structure as yours, but included "accepts_nested_attributes_for" class methods on the parent and join models. In your case it would be:

```
class Offering < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: :enrolments
  has_many :enrolments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrolments
end

class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offering
  belongs_to :student
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offerings, through: :enrolments
  has_many :enrolments
end
```

I also needed to do a few things to dynamically create the association based on the value of another input (in your case, the text input for entering Student IDs):

**1. Add association form helpers to my view.** Use the simple_fields_for and association helpers to "nest" the Enrolment and Student form fields in the Offering#show view (this worked for me when I included the code below in the parent model's _form partial, even though you'll be adding it to the show.html.erb file):

```
<%= simple_form_for @offering do |f| %>
    <h4>Add Student</h4>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :enrolments do |e| %>
        <p>Student ID: <%= text_field_tag 'sid' %><br><span id="student_name"></span></p>
        <span style="display:none;"><%= e.association :student, collection: [] %></span>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Add Student" %></p>
 <% end %>
```

**2. Create an AJAX call to dynamically write to the view.** Add an ajax call to the parent model's js.coffee file to use the value of the text input to dynamically create the association:

```
# offering.js.coffee

$('form').on 'blur', '[id="sid"]', (event) ->
        $.ajax
          url: '/set_student_id/'
          type: 'GET'
          dataType: 'json'
          json: true
          data: {student_id: $("input[id='sid']").val()}
          success: (data) ->
            $("[id$='student_id']").html(data.sid)
            $("[id='student_name']).html(data.name)
          error: (data) ->
            console.log "error"
```

**3. Add an action to handle the ajax call in the parent model's controller.** Use the same name as the 'url' value in the ajax call for the action (and make sure the join and child model attributes are permitted):

```
# offerings_controller.rb

def set_student_id
    student = Student.find_by(sid: params[:student_id])
    @sid = "<option value='#{student.id}' selected='selected'>#{student.name}</option>"
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {sid: @sid, name: student.name} }
    end
end

def offering_params
    params.require(:offering).permit(enrolments_attributes:[:id, :student_id, students_attributes: [:id, :name]])
end
```

**4. Update the /config/routes.rb file for the ajax callback.** Make sure the 'url' value you include in the ajax call is routed to the correct action in the parent model's controller:

```
get "/set_student_id/", to: "offerings#set_student_id"
```

The Simple Form association helper creates a select list by default. This code should dynamically add the Student that matches the sid entered as the selected option in the list and dynamically display the Student name beneath the sid form input once the input loses focus (the blur event in the jquery).

Hope this helps.